# How to configure EF Core to handle a one-to-one relationship when an entity doesn't exist yet

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm trying to configure EF Core (6.0.3), along with Npgsql (6.0.3) for Postgres, to create a one-to-one mapping between two entities, but allow for the situation where the related entity might not exist yet.

For example, EntityA might be related to EntityB via the foreign key property of EntityBId. I know how to handle if EntityBId is null, but how do you handle if EntityBId has a value, and EntityB doesn't exist yet (but eventually will)?

I have tried using this configuration...

```cs
// Entity definitions
public EntityA
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public long? EntityBId { get; set; }
   public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}
public EntityB
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
}


// EF Core Entity Type Configuration
builder.HasOne(entityA => entityA.EntityB)
   .WithOne()
   .IsRequired(false);
```

... but this doesn't work. I get foreign key constraint errors when I try to insert EntityA with a value for EntityBId, and EntityB doesn't exist yet.

What am I doing wrong?  Is this scenario even possible?

Comment: *... but this doesn't work.* - expand please. Also, do these entities share a key value?

Comment: I get foreign key violation errors.  I've updated my question to elaborate on the errors.

Comment: *how do you handle if EntityBId has a value, and EntityB doesn't exist yet (but eventually will)?* - you can't; if EntityB doesn't exist then what ID could you possibly be putting into EntityBId?

Comment: This happens when EntityA arrives from one microservice, and EntityB arrives from another microservice.  EntityA can arrive before EntityB.  So EntityA could indeed have a value for EntityBId, even though EntityB hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27821, see answer there.